# Explanation for nested module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, nested, nested-loops

I have a piece of code in an old code base that contains nested `module.exports` like the following. I haven't seen such a form of export before. Can some please explain or atleast point me to the right articles?

```
module.exports = function something(options) {

   someMethod = new func1(options);

   module.exports.anotherFunc = function (req, res) {
       someMethod.anotherFunc1(req, res);
   };

   module.exports.func1 = someMethod.func3;

   return function func4(req, res, next) {
       someMethod.anotherFunc1(req, res);
       next();
   };
};
```

Comment: Wow! That is a bit convoluted. It kind of looks like the original developer was trying to use recursion and didn't quite know how.

Comment: This is horrible code. Calling a function should never mutate exports. You will not find any article that recommends this.

Answer (score 0):

It could have been an attempt at generating modules on the fly in order to share global state across the application, however it's not clear to me how you would then import such modules. I think it's probably bad design more than anything; by the look of it these inner `exports` statements look totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I landed here because I encountered some code like the following example. In my case, it turns out that `exports` was not actually being changed inside other exports - it was being used to call other exported functions - but it was still confusing.

```js
exports.sumTwoNumbers = function sumTwoNumbers(a, b) {
  return a + b
}

exports.addOne = function addOne(n) {
  return exports.sumTwoNumbers(n, 1) // nested `exports`?
}

exports.foo = function foo(n) {
  if(exports.sumTwoNumbers(n, 2) === 3) {
    return "bar"
  }
}
```

I refactored it to be clearer by separating the functions from the exports assignments:

```js
// exports.sumTwoNumbers = function sumTwoNumbers(a, b) {
//   return a + b
// }

const sumTwoNumbers = (a, b) =>   a + b
exports.sumTwoNumbers = sumTwoNumbers;
```

since the property and the function name are the same, this can be written using object shorthand notation

```js
exports = {
  sumTwoNumbers,
}
```

Final refactored code

```js
const sumTwoNumbers = (a, b) =>   a + b
const addOne = (n) => sumTwoNumbers(n, 1)
const foo = (n) => {
  if(sumTwoNumbers(n, 2) === 3) {
    return "bar"
  }
}

exports = {
  sumTwoNumbers,
  addOne,
  foo
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This looks like an attempt to write an IIFE gone horribly wrong. It probably should simply be

```
// module-local variable
const someMethod = new func1(options);

module.exports = function func4(req, res, next) {
    someMethod.anotherFunc1(req, res);
    next();
};

module.exports.anotherFunc = function (req, res) {
    someMethod.anotherFunc1(req, res);
};

module.exports.func1 = someMethod.func3;
```